# Windows 10: appium doctor --android shows --android-coverage expecting an argument

Tags: appium-android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSCPa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBN3w.png)

Hi, all. I was trying to verify if appium is installed correctly. After running appium doctor -android, it shows error, Expecting one argument for --android-coverage. The solutions I found here are for  --app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kxuemz
https://ibb.co/cUaVte
https://ibb.co/fLtGYe
I had configure ANDROID_HOME, but appium shows I had not configured ANDROID_HOME.

Comment: I had fixed it. Thanks.